# Qmetry- How to use appium driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, appium, qaf

In QMetry, I am trying to switch from appiumDriver to androidDriver in one of test case. This need arised due to one of the function `driver.isKeyboardShown()` is showing as undefined for the appium. So need to change it to androidDriver and use this function.

Currently in Qmetry project, for appiumDriver capabilities are set in application.properties file as :

```
driver.name=appiumDriver
appium.capabilities.driverClass=io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver
```

& using driver in test case as:

```
AppiumDriver driver = (AppiumDriver) new WebDriverTestBase().getDriver().getUnderLayingDriver();
```

Now want to switch to androidDriver.

Not sure how to switch from AppiumDriver to androidDriver in run time through java code.

How can I achieve this through code?  Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to cast it to AndroidDriver when using Android Driver.

```
driver.name=appiumDriver
appium.capabilities.driverClass=io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
```

Both of below statements should work:

```
AppiumDriver driver = (AppiumDriver) new WebDriverTestBase().getDriver().getUnderLayingDriver();

AndroidDriver driver = (AndroidDriver) new WebDriverTestBase().getDriver().getUnderLayingDriver();
```